# What is the period of the function $f(x)=1-2\sin^2(2x)$?

Tags: functions, trigonometry

What is the period of the function $f(x)=1-2\sin^2(2x)$?

A periodic function is a function that repeats its values at regular intervals.

The sine function is a periodic function with a period of $2\pi$.

Does this make $f(x)$ also periodic with a period of $2\pi$ radians? If not, what is the approach?

Comment: This has the same period as $\sin^2 (2x)$, which is $\frac{\pi}{2}$. Alternatively, use the identity $$1- 2 \sin^2 (2x) = \cos (4x)$$ whose period is indeed $\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Comment: The period of $f(x)=1-2 \sin^2(2 x)$ is $T=\frac{\pi}{2}$ which you can deduce from the period of $\sin(2 x)$ which is $\pi$ and the fact that $\sin^2(2 x)=\sin^2\left(2 \left(x+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\right)$ since $y^2=(-y)^2$.

Comment: @Crostul, how do we find that the period of $\cos(4x)$ is $\frac{\pi}{2}$?

Comment: The period of $\cos(4 x)$ is $\frac{\pi}{2}$ since the period of $\cos(x)$ is $2 \pi$ and $\frac{2 \pi}{4}=\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

As you already observed, the functions $x\longmapsto \sin x$ and $x\longmapsto \cos x$ are periodic with minimal period $2\pi$.

However, they also satisfy \begin{align}\sin(x+\pi) &= -\sin(x)\\ \cos(x+\pi) &=-\cos(x).\end{align}

Thus, $x\longmapsto (\sin x)^2$ has a period of $\pi$, and $x\longmapsto (\sin(2x))^2$ has a period of only $\frac{\pi}{2}$.